# Ocaml recursion: Pattern Matching

Tags: eclipse, recursion, ocaml

I am trying to write to recursive fn that changes a unlabelled tree to a labelled tree with the use of a helper function.

required info:

```
type nucleotide = 
| G | C
| A | T 

type helix = nucleotide list

type tree = 
| Leaf of helix 
| Node of tree * tree

type labeled_tree =
| LLeaf of helix
| LNode of labeled_tree * helix * labeled_tree
```

This is the helper function:

```
let rec guess_parent_helix (x1: helix) (x2: helix) : helix =
 begin match (x1, x2) with
 ([], []) -> []
 | (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) ->
   (if h1 = h2 then h1 else A) :: guess_parent_helix t1 t2
 | _ -> failwith "invalid input: x1 and x2 have unequal lengths"
 end
```

I have written the following function but am unable to compile as it says I have not exhausted the pattern matching : Node( (Node(_ , _ ),_) ). What I do not understand is, how is this not included in the Node(rt,lt) pattern match:

```
let rec add_ancestor_labels (r: tree) : labeled_tree =
  begin match r with
    | Leaf x -> LLeaf x
    | Node (lt,rt) -> 
        begin match r with
        | Leaf x -> LLeaf x
        | Node (Leaf[m], Leaf[n]) -> 
            LNode (add_ancestor_labels lt, guess_parent_helix [m] [n], add_ancestor_labels rt) 
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the inner match that's incomplete. The outer match is fine.

**Update**

The code as it stands doesn't make a lot of sense. After matching `r` and finding that it's an internal node, you match `r` again. There's no need to do this, you already know it's an internal node.

It's hard to give specific advice since I don't know what the labels are supposed to look like. Here is some code that sets each label to the concatenation of the nucleotides below it:

```
let labeled_tree_of_tree tree =
    let rec go t =
        match t with
        | Leaf x -> (x, LLeaf x)
        | Node (lt, rt) ->
            let (llabel, llt) = go lt in
            let (rlabel, lrt) = go rt in
            let label = llabel @ rlabel in
            (label, LNode (llt, label, lrt))
    in
    let (_, ltree) = go tree in
    ltree
```

Maybe this will give a feel for what your code might look like. No doubt it will be more complicated than this.

Comment: Thank you sir. Though I still dont understand as I type other cases without matching them to helices(eg[n]) how shall I pass arguments to the helper function.
for eg | Node(Node(_,_),Node(_,_))-> ??

Comment: The labels are supposed to the output of the helper function. It takes two helices and outputs a single one. As the type tree had Node of tree*tree and labelled trees have nodes of labeled_tree*helix*labeled_tree the helices have to be calculated from the bottom node up as far as I understand. I get how this should work put am having problems implementing this. I understand your point about matching against r twice being redundant but am still having problems getting it to compile. I am posting my updated code as the next answer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Exhaustiveness checking only applies to the cases of a single match. Information about which cases are possible will not be propagated to nested matches, which can occasionally lead to some "impossible" cases.

Where possible, it is better to extend the match with additional cases like this:

```
let rec add_ancestor_labels = function
  | Leaf x -> LLeaf x
  | Node (Leaf x, Leaf y) ->
     LNode (LLeaf x,
            guess_parent_helix x y,
            LLeaf y)
  | Node (Leaf x, Node (l, r)) ->
     LNode (LLeaf x,
            ...,
            LNode (add_ancestor_labels l,
                   ...,
                   add_ancestor_labels r))
  | Node (Node ..., Leaf x) -> ...
  | Node (Node ..., Node ...) -> ...
```

An alternative to repeating the outermost constructor is to bind the arguments to variables and then match on those:

```
let rec add_ancestor_labels = function
  | Leaf x -> LLeaf x
  | Node (l, r) ->
     begin
       match l, r with
        | ...
     end
```

Finally, note that `Leaf [m]` only matches leaves that have helixes of length 1 - leaves with helixes of other lengths are unhandled. It's not clear whether this is what you intended, but exhaustiveness checking will warn if you forget to handle the case of leaves of other lengths.

The warning messages that OCaml gives you for nonexhaustive matches should include some of the missing cases, so do read them carefully.

As for your function, I *think* it would be written like this:

```
let add_ancestor_labels tree =
  let rec label = function
    | Leaf x -> x, LLeaf x
    | Node (left, right) ->
       let llabel, ltree = label left in
       let rlabel, rtree = label right in
       let l = guess_parent_helix llabel rlabel in
       l, LNode (ltree, l, rtree) in
  snd (label tree)
```

(Which is very similar to Jeffrey's suggestion.)

Comment: The labels are supposed to the output of the helper function. It takes two helices and outputs a single one. As the type tree had Node of tree*tree and labelled trees have nodes of labeled_tree*helix*labeled_tree the helices have to be calculated from the bottom node up as far as I understand. I get how this should work put am having problems implementing this.  I am posting my updated code as the next answer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
 let rec add_ancestor_labels (r: tree) : labeled_tree =
begin match r with
| Leaf x -> LLeaf x
| Node (lt,rt) -> 
    begin match (lt, rt) with
    | (Leaf m, Leaf n) -> 
        LNode (LLeaf m, guess_parent_helix m n, 
        LLeaf n) 
    | (lt,Leaf n)-> LNode(add_ancestor_labels lt, 
    guess_parent_helix (helix_of_tree (add_ancestor_labels lt)) n, LLeaf n)
    | (Leaf m,rt)->LNode(LLeaf m, guess_parent_helix 
    (helix_of_tree(add_ancestor_labels rt)) m, add_ancestor_labels rt)
    | (_,_)-> failwith"invalid input"
    end
end
```

Managed to finish it. Thank you for your help.